# Is "I mostly agree with what you said" correct?

Tags: grammaticality, phrase-request, idiomatic-language

How can I say that I mostly agree with somebody's statement.

Comment: Just to clarify: do you mean that your **level of agreement** with someone's statement is high, but not total; or do you mean that, of the things that were said you **agree with some, but not others**?

Answer (score 6):

It's a twofold question but before you give any further detail, here's a general explanation:

1. **"I mostly agree with what you said"** - *This refers to how much you agree with somebody's statement.* Based on the word **mostly**, here's a chart for you:

[image: level of agreement from 100% to 0%]

2. **"I agree with mostly everything that you said"** - *This refers to the amount of information you agree with.*

   - I agree that most of what you said is true, but not everything.
   - I have a few doubts about some things that you said.

Comment: Hmm... I would say "I agree with *most of everything* that you said."

Comment: @user3169 The phrasing "most of everything" seems strange to me (AmE). I might say "I agree with **most of what** you said." or  "I agree with **almost everything** that you said".

Comment: @ColleenV I would say, "I agree with mostly everything you said."